# How to Pass a variable just after $_get

Tags: javascript, php, html

I  have form passing value for **s**

```
<input type="text" name="s" placeholder="Search names" value="<?php if(!empty($_GET['s'])){echo $_GET['s']; }?>"/>
```

Using this currently i am able to do like this

example.com/?=searchterm

But i want an extra static part ***&c=73*** just after searchterm like

example.com/?=searchterm&c=73

i tried using `echo $_GET['s']; echo '&c=73';` but it didn't work.

Please guide me as i am new to php.

Comment: `echo $_GET['c'];`  assuming you did the rest correctly. The `&` is a seperator an allows PHP to make the `$_GET` array from the querystring

Comment: You would need to use a separate form field (likely hidden) that would be submitted with the form data. `<input type='hidden' name='c' value='73'>`

Comment: @Jonathan can you please show me a demo? i am new to php

Comment: @Jonathan will it pass if i add the input tag you wrote on comment?

Comment: Try it. That is what I would do, but there are a hundred ways it might or might not work. You didn't post your form code or how the form is submitted, so I would have no idea.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create another input of `type="hidden"` with a `name="c"`

The access it in php as `$_GET['c']`

```
<input type="text" name="s" placeholder="Search names" value="<?php if(!empty($_GET['s'])){echo $_GET['s']; }?>"/>

<input type="hidden" name="c" value="73"/>
```

Comment: Just amazing! Thank You